# Is there any way to get list of values from HashMap contains of ArrayList of HashMaps?

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, hashmap

I want to get a List of Data Transfer Objects from the response i got from the third party API.
The structure of the third party API's response is as follows:

```
Map<String,Object>
{
    {
        String -> ArrayList{
                        <Key,Value(DTO)>,
                        <Key,Value(DTO)>,
                        <Key,Value(DTO)>,
                        ...
                    }
    },

    {
        String -> Hashmap
    }
}
```

Response Type: `Map(String,Object)`

I got two key-value pairs. **1(String,ArrayList ( HashMap(s)... ) ) , 2(String,HashMap)**

Now I want the list of the values of all the ***HashMaps*** of ***ArrayList***.

I want the List as :

```
List<DTO>{
    {
        "key":"value",
        "key":"value"
    },
    {
        "key":"value",
        "key":"value",
        "key":"value",
        "key":"value"
    }
}
```

sample response from api:

```
{ "one": [ 0 : { "id":"435453ty5g8437t5g734tr", "name":"name1", "address":"add", "field":"new field" }, 1: { "id":"4fr74g8fg48346rt83486tf", "name":"name2", "address":"add1", "field":"new field22" } ], 
 "meta": { "current_page":1, "records_per_page":20, "total_records":null } }
```

how i need :

```
[ { "id":"435453ty5g8437t5g734tr", "name":"name1", "address":"add", "field":"new field" }, 
  { "id":"4fr74g8fg48346rt83486tf", "name":"name2", "address":"add1", "field":"new field22" } ]
```

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: I don't get your question.

Comment: Could you please paste your sample response from third party API and also the sample response how you need

Comment: When you add information about your question, please edit your post to add the content into it, for this time I've done it for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may :

1. filter the entries where the values is a `List`
2. Map from `Object` to `List<Map<String, DTO>>`
3. `flatMap` to put all maps together in the same stream
4. Collect all

This is the unchecked version, for the generic type of the `List`

```
List<Map<String, DTO>> result =
         content.values().stream()
                         .filter(value -> value instanceof List)
                         .map(value -> (List<Map<String, DTO>>) value)
                         .flatMap(List::stream)
                         .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(result);
```

> [`> Online Demo`](https://ideone.com/1HsAyk)

Comment: @TrushitShekhda I was not sure about the result you wanted, I add a flatMap operation to remove a level of List in the result